# Error using AlexNet for Transfer Learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I'm trying to do Transfer Learning in AlexNet, from Fashion MNIST to MNIST.
The error I'm receiving is

InvalidArgumentError

Traceback (most recent call last) 
 in () 
2 #alex1.compile(optimizer='adam',loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
3 tic = time.time() 
----> 4 history = alex1.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=20, validation_data=(x_val2, y_val2))
5 toc = time.time()
6 elapsed_time = toc-tic

1 frames 
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in
 quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
53 ctx.ensure_initialized()
54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
57     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'Equal' defined at (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"**main**", mod_spec)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in 
app.launch_new_instance()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
app.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 499, in start
self.io_loop.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
self._run_once()
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
handle._run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
handler_func(fileobj, events)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 452, in _handle_events
self._handle_recv()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 481, in _handle_recv
self._run_callback(callback, msg)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 431, in _run_callback
callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
handler(stream, idents, msg)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
user_expressions, allow_stdin)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
if self.run_code(code, result):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "", line 4, in 
history = alex1.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=20, validation_data=(x_val2, y_val2))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 864, in train_step
return self.compute_metrics(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 957, in compute_metrics
self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 459, in update_state
metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 70, in decorated
update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 178, in update_state_fn
return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 729, in update_state
matches = ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 4086, in sparse_categorical_accuracy
return tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true, y_pred), backend.floatx())
Node: 'Equal'
required broadcastable shapes
[[{{node Equal}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_7770]

```
   # Download Fashion MNIST
   import torch
   import torch.nn as nn
   import torch.nn.functional as F
   import torch.optim as optim
   from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import _LRScheduler
   import torch.utils.data as data

   import torchvision.transforms as transforms
   import torchvision.datasets as datasets
   from torchvision import models

   objects = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
   (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = objects.load_data()
   x_train = tf.pad(x_train, [[0, 0], [2,2], [2,2]])/255
   x_test = tf.pad(x_test, [[0, 0], [2,2], [2,2]])/255
   x_train = tf.expand_dims(x_train, axis=3, name=None)
   x_test = tf.expand_dims(x_test, axis=3, name=None)
   x_train = tf.repeat(x_train, 3, axis=3)
   x_test = tf.repeat(x_test, 3, axis=3)
   x_val = x_train[-2000:,:,:,:]
   y_val = y_train[-2000:]
   x_train = x_train[:-2000,:,:,:]
   y_train = y_train[:-2000] 

   # Load MNIST
   import tensorflow as tf

   objects = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
   (x_train2, y_train2), (x_test2, y_test2) = objects.load_data()
   
   # Create AlexNet
   import keras
   from numpy import mean
   from numpy import std
   from matplotlib import pyplot
   from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
   from keras.models import Sequential
   from keras.layers import Conv2D
   from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
   from keras.layers import Dense
   from keras.layers import Flatten
   from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
   import torch
   import tensorflow.keras
   from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models, losses

   model = models.Sequential()
   model.add(layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(224, 224, interpolation="bilinear", 
   input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
   model.add(layers.Conv2D(96, 11, strides=4, padding='same'))
   model.add(layers.Lambda(tf.nn.local_response_normalization))
   model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
   model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(3, strides=2))
   model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, 5, strides=4, padding='same'))
   model.add(layers.Lambda(tf.nn.local_response_normalization))
   model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
   model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(3, strides=2))
   model.add(layers.Conv2D(384, 3, strides=4, padding='same'))
   model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
   model.add(layers.Conv2D(384, 3, strides=4, padding='same'))
   model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
   model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, 3, strides=4, padding='same'))
   model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
   model.add(layers.Flatten())
   model.add(layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
   model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
   model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

   alex = model
   alex.summary()

   print(alex)

   # Transfer Learning
   from tensorflow import keras
   from keras.layers import Dropout
   from keras.models import Model

   for layer in alex.layers[:-1]:
      layer.trainable = False
   #x = alex.layers[2].output
   #x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
   #x = Dense(32,activation='relu')(x)
   #x = Dense(16,activation='relu')(x)
   predictions = Dense(10,activation='softmax')(x)

   alex1 = Model(alex.input,predictions)
   alex1.summary()

   # Compile
   alex1.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, metrics= 
     ['accuracy'])
   
   tic = time.time()
   history = alex1.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=20, validation_data=(x_val2, 
     y_val2))
   toc = time.time()
   elapsed_time = toc-tic
   print(elapsed_time)
```

I've seen that this is usually because the number of labels, but here both datasets have 10 classes. Any idea or suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you comment out the line `x = alex.layers[2].output` and the following? By the way, your _alex_ network is not trained.

Comment: @elbe I just wanted to use the last layer. About the training, isn't it supposed to be layers.trainable=False? Sorry, I'm newbie at this. Thanks